# Change `$column-width` at breakpoint, but not number of columns

Tags: css, susy-compass

Most Susy examples I've seen seem to handle situations where the amount of columns changes at a given breakpoint, i.e.:

```
$total-columns: 4;
$large: 12;

// code based on 4 columns

@include at-breakpoint($large) {
    // code based on 12 columns
}
```

But what about when you want the number of columns to remain the same, but (for example) **just** change the column width? Like this:

```
$total-columns: 12;
$column-width: 3em;

$large: 64em;
$large-column-width: 3.75em;

@include at-breakpoint($large) {
    $column-width: $large-column-width; // automagically changes previously declared column-widths.
}
```

I would want anything using `columns()` or `span-columns()` before the breakpoint to automatically adjust their values to the new column-width *without* having to redeclare them.

So...

```
foo { @include span-columns(4, $total-columns); }
```

would not change at the breakpoint, but *the width of the columns would*, automatically.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Susy 2 solves this problem using the new [susy-breakpoint](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#breakpoint) with a [more powerful shorthand syntax](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/shorthand/).  But the Susy 1 approach isn't much more complex. The `at-breakpoint` mixin is a simple wrapper for two actions:

1. Set up a media-query.
2. Change the global Susy settings *inside* that media-query block.

I recommend downloading Breakpoint (or another plugin like it) to handle the media-query side of things, but you can also do it by hand. Susy provides a mixin to handle the second part (`with-grid-settings`). If you put those two together, you have a more powerful version of `at-breakpoint`.

```
$large: 64em;
$large-column-width: 3.75em;

@media (min-width: $large) {
  @include with-grid-settings($column-width: $large-column-width) {
    // new column-width applied to code in here.
  }
}
```